# Replacement for Title attribute that work in touch screen environment

Tags: javascript, css, html, title

I have to use `title` attribute to show the entire text in case the label size decreases and forces an `ellipsis`. Now the problem is my page might be accessed by touch interface users and they might not have the option to hover (apart from galaxy note users).

I was hoping someone is aware of a control within HTML5/HTML for touch devices which will toast the title text on the screen next to a div on tapping the div for complete text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [usage of title](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/) & [abuse of title tags](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2012/01/html5-accessibility-chops-title-attribute-use-and-abuse/). HTML5 has not spoken on this so far.

You might need to implement the double tab event yourself using js or use [jquery doubletap](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/doubletap-event)

Alternatively, hover event is implemented by many mobiles devices to be fired on the first tap... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eH6PX/1/)

CSS

```
span {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

span:hover {    
    overflow: visible;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<span>Test test test test test test</span>
```

Comment: At the moment I am looking to support only ios and android browsers. So this works for me. Thanks!